# Transforming a 3x3 two-dimensional array in a 6x6 symmetrical two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to solve an exercise that requires:

- fill randomly a 3x3 two-dimensional array

- transform the array in a second one with dimension 6x6:

1  2  3         1  2  3   3  2  1

4  5  6     ->    4  5  6   6  5 4

7  8  9         7  8  9   9  8  7

7  8  9   9  8  7

4  5  6   6  5  4

1  2  3   3  2  1

I can't get it working tho' I think the logic must be right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 #define DIM 3

int main()
{
int i, j, a[DIM][DIM],a1[DIM][DIM], a2[DIM][DIM], a3[DIM][DIM], b[2*DIM][2*DIM];
srand(time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
    {
    printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
    {
        a1[i][j] = a[i][DIM - 1 - j];
        a2[i][j] = a[DIM - 1 -j][j];
        a3[i][j] = a2[i][DIM - 1 - j];

        if(i < DIM && j < DIM)
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        if(i < DIM && j >= DIM)
            b[i][j] = a1[i][j];
        if(i >= DIM && j < DIM)
            b[i][j] = a2[i][j];
        if(i >= DIM && j >= DIM)
            b[i][j] = a3[i][j];
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < 2*DIM; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2*DIM; j++)
    {
    printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: by writing the logic out on paper and then translating it to C

Comment: People on StackOverflow are generally more willing to help when you show you've put some effort into solving the problem you're asking for help with. Showing that you've filled in the array isn't the same as showing you've actually tried to solve the actual problem at hand. You should do some research, plot out a solution and try it out, no matter how naive the solution is. If you still have specific problems, then you could come back and ask for help.

Comment: Sorry about it then. I'll try my own solution first

Comment: I changed the code. I'm trying to solve it but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few points that should help you to get where you want to go:

- You are making four copies of a three by three array.

  - You need a nested for loop to iterate over the original array
  - Inside the for loop you will be making four assignments, one for each copy
- Each copy has a different location

  - When you make the copies you will need to add an offset to each index
  - This is best done by just using the index of what was the value in the upper left corner
- Each copy goes in different directions

  - Whenever a dimension is going in the wrong dimension, you can simply subtract the index

Anything else?

Comment: Could you check the updated code? I tried to implement what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you always fill the 6 X 6 matrix in the same way shown in the example, then you can use the following code,

```
m=0;
fl1=0;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    n=0;
    fl2=0;
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
       b[i][j] = a[m][n];   
       if(n==3)
       {
          fl2=1;   
       }
       if(fl2==0)
       {
          n++;
       }
       else
       {
          n--;
       }
    }
    if(m==3)
    {
       fl1=1;
    }
    if(fl1==0)
    {
       m++;
    }
    else
    {
       m--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < DIM*2; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < DIM*2; j++){
        b[i][j]=a[i-(i>=DIM)*((i-DIM)*2+1)][j-(j>=DIM)*((j-DIM)*2+1)];
    }
}
```